# populate a textbox based on 2 comboboxes

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have two "combo boxes" and one "txtbox" in my userform, In workbook "sheet1" i have names on column A and Month on column B and columns C to N are Jan. to Dec. which contain production hours for each name/specific month

```
-cboName
-cboMonth
-txtHours
```

I use below code to populate txtHours

```
Private Sub cboName_Change()
    Dim EName As String
    Dim Row, Col As Integer
    EName = Me.cboName.Text        
    If EName <> "" Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
           Row = .Match(EName, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A100"), 0)  
           GetMonthNum (Me.cboMonth.Text)
           txtShiftHours.Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Row + 1, Col + 3)
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GetMonthNum(Month As String)

    Select Case Month
        Case Jan
            Col = 3
        Case Feb
            Col = 4
        Case Mar
            Col = 5
        Case Apr
            Col = 6
        Case May
            Col = 7
        Case June
            Col = 8
        Case July
            Col = 9
        Case Aug
            Col = 10
        Case Sept
            Col = 11
        Case Oct
            Col = 12
        Case Nov
            Col = 13
        Case Dec
            Col = 14
        End Select
        End Sub
```

but regardless of month selection on cboMonth,txtProduct is populated with column 3 cuz this line

```
txtShiftHours.Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Row + 1, Col + 3)
```

Please help me
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had several issues:

- Your `Case` statements were checking the value of the String variable `Month` against undefined variables such as `Jan`, `Feb`, etc.  This should have been checking against String literals such as `"Jan"`, `"Feb"`, etc.
- In your `GetMonthNum` subroutine, you were assigning a value to an undefined variable `Col`.
- In your `cboName_Change` subroutine you were using a variable `Col` which had never been assigned a value, so it would have had the default value of zero.

You also had some minor issues, which wouldn't have stopped your code from working, but could lead to problems down the track:

- You used several variable names (`Row`, `Month`) which are the same as built in Functions / Properties within VBA.  This is usually a very bad idea.
- You declared `Row` as a `Variant`, despite declaring `Col` as an `Integer`.
- It's a good idea to define row and column variables to be `Long` rather than `Integer` - the maximum number of rows in Excel is now 1048576, but an `Integer` can only hold numbers up to 65536.

It is also a good idea to always include the `Option Explicit` statement as the first line of each of your code modules.  This tells the compiler to check that all your variables have been declared, and thus prevents many typos and attempts to use variables in one subroutine which are local to another subroutine.

I have refactored your code and hopefully it should now work.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboName_Change()
    Dim EName As String
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long
    EName = Me.cboName.Text        
    If EName <> "" Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
           RowNum = .Match(EName, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A100"), 0)  
           ColNum = GetMonthNum(Me.cboMonth.Text) + 2
           txtShiftHours.Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(RowNum + 1, ColNum)
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetMonthNum(Mth As String) As Long
    Select Case Mth
        Case "Jan":  GetMonthNum = 1
        Case "Feb":  GetMonthNum = 2
        Case "Mar":  GetMonthNum = 3
        Case "Apr":  GetMonthNum = 4
        Case "May":  GetMonthNum = 5
        Case "June": GetMonthNum = 6
        Case "July": GetMonthNum = 7
        Case "Aug":  GetMonthNum = 8
        Case "Sept": GetMonthNum = 9
        Case "Oct":  GetMonthNum = 10
        Case "Nov":  GetMonthNum = 11
        Case "Dec":  GetMonthNum = 12
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @YowE3K , you taught and helped me even more than i asked,sounds nice. please forgive my rudeness for mentioning your mistype The second End Sub should change to End function

Comment: @Mansour - Mistake now corrected.  (And I definitely do NOT consider it rude to point out an inaccuracy!  Many thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use some of Excel's `Date & Time` built-in functions, to replace your entire `Private Sub GetMonthNum(Month As String)` with the 1 line of code below:

```
ColNum = Month(DateValue("1/" & Me.cboMonth.Text & "/2017")) + 2
```

**Explanation**: since your `cboMonth` Combo-Box has month strings in the `mmm` month format. If you select "Feb", then when you get to this section `("1/" & Me.cboMonth.Text & "/2017")` you are getting "1/Feb/2017".

When adding `DateValue` before, you get `1/Feb/2017`, and when adding the `Month` before, the result is **2**.

Comment: @Mansour  have you read my answer here on how to shorten your code?

Comment: Yep, I checked it ,it's wonderful your code is much shorter and easier. But there's just one point, does this code work with calendars other than Gregorian? I use Persian calendar(solar based calendar with Persian or Farsi Month names ) and I'm able to adapt @YowE code to my calendar.If i use Gregorian calendar i certainly use your fantastic code.

Comment: @Mansour  haven't tried it, try and see. Let me know, I'm curious if it does

Comment: As i said it works ( if i'm right ) with Gregorian calendar but i dont think it works with other ones. i hope i could explain it well. At present, I'm using your code on a form